# Query error when trying to SELECT data in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, python

I'm just getting started with PostgreSQL and have a bit of a problem. I am using Psycopg2 and hosting the PostgreSQL database on AWS RDS. Here is the query I am trying to execute:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM fqdn AS domain WHERE domain.fqdn IS {0}'.format(fqdn_str))
```

fqdn_str is a domain name like this:

```
https://www.example.com
```

and the fqdn table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE fqdn (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    fqdn TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_last_crawled TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (fqdn)
);
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "https"
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong so I would appreciate a little bit of help with this. If you need any more information then please let me know. Thank you.

Edit:

If I change the format string to %s as shown in the documentation I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: The error message hints that string literal quotes must be added... try something like `cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM fqdn AS domain WHERE domain.fqdn IS \'{0}\''.format(fqdn_str))`

Comment: I suggest you to read [Basic module usage](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html). the command above has SQL injection vulnerability. You should use a syntax like `cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM fqdn AS domain WHERE domain.fqdn IS %s', (fqdn_str))`

Comment: @SahapAsci Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, if I try and use %s instead, I get the error message shown in my edited question.

Comment: Have you tried to use `=` instead of `IS`?

Comment: @SahapAsci I think there needs to be a comma after `fqdn_str` in the code you suggested in your comment. I added an answer with my reasoning.

Comment: @Ralf thanks for the correction

Answer (score 6):

As user @SahapAsci suggested in a comment to the question, you should use parameters for your SQL query (read the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)) to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

The docs I linked even have a nice note:

[image]

But I suspect the code @SahapAsci suggested in their comment has a small error. The user suggested this code:

```
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT id FROM fqdn AS domain WHERE domain.fqdn IS %s',
    (fqdn_str))
```

But I think you need to add a comma to the tuple of parameters, because otherwise it won't be a tuple but just a single string, which will be interpreted as an iterable and only use the first char (and then throw the error you mentioned: `"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"`). The docs I linked even have a note to be careful about this specific case.

And you probably should us `=` instead of `IS`, but I'm not dead certain on that last part.

So your final code should probably look like this:

```
cursor.execute(
    'SELECT id FROM fqdn AS domain WHERE domain.fqdn = %s',
    (fqdn_str, ))
```

Comment: "But I think you need to add a comma to the tuple of parameters," => it's indeed required, else it's not a tuple. Or you can use a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change IS by = in your WHERE clause.

```
CREATE TABLE T(ID text);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('https://www.example.com');
```

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID IS 'https://www.example.com';
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'https://www.example.com'"
>   LINE 1: SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID IS 'https://www.example.com';

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID = 'https://www.example.com';
```

```
| id                      |
| :---------------------- |
| https://www.example.com |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cd59cb9d430edf00d8e70e515b4a01a5)*